# Is it possible to change the form icon in the caption bar of modal and non-modal forms at run-time?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

Using Delphi 2010.

I am looking for (possibly) a function or procedure which can be passed a TForm & a image (TImage or TBitmap) and it can change the forms icon, either overwriting the current one, or  writing the new one in a particular location, adjusting the caption when necessary.  Must work with both modal and non-modal forms.

Example:

procedure ChangeFormIcon(AForm: TForm; AIcon: TBitmap;

All other suggestions welcomed

Thanx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do what you want. I've assumed that you are using 32bpp bitmaps with, potentially, alpha blending. If you want to use mask based transparency then you would need to re-work the code to create an appropriate mask bitmap.

```
procedure CopyBitmapToIcon(Bitmap: TBitmap; Icon: TIcon);
var
  MonoBitmap: HBITMAP;
  IconInfo: TIconInfo;
  IconHandle: HICON;
begin
  MonoBitmap := CreateBitmap(Bitmap.Width, Bitmap.Height, 1, 1, 0);
  Try
    FillChar(IconInfo, SizeOf(IconInfo), 0);
    IconInfo.fIcon := True;
    IconInfo.hbmMask := MonoBitmap;
    IconInfo.hbmColor := Bitmap.Handle;
    IconHandle := CreateIconIndirect(IconInfo);
    if IconHandle=0 then begin
      RaiseLastOSError;
    end;
    Icon.Handle := IconHandle;
  Finally
    DeleteObject(MonoBitmap);
  End;
end;

procedure TMyForm.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Bitmap: TBitmap;
  Icon: TIcon;
begin
  Icon := Self.Icon;
  Bitmap := TBitmap.Create;
  try
    Bitmap.PixelFormat := pf32bit;
    Bitmap.SetSize(Icon.Width, Icon.Height);
    Bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Style := bsSolid;
    Bitmap.Canvas.Brush.Color := clRed;
    Bitmap.Canvas.FillRect(Rect(0, 0, Icon.Width, Icon.Height));
    CopyBitmapToIcon(Bitmap, Icon);
  finally
    Bitmap.Free;
  end;
end;
```